# react-beautiful-dnd nested list drag to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm creating a sortable tree view with 'react-beautiful-dnd' (because `react-sortable-tree` is broken with react@17+)

the storybook in doc site has implemented a nested list

https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.app/?path=/story/complex-vertical-list--nested-vertical-lists

but it can not drag an item from "second level" to "top level" (making a child become a sibling of its parent)

I have tried to make all `<Droppable />` with the same type, but it doesn't work well

Comment: Hello did you found a solution ?

Comment: @UgoLfe so sad, I eventually use react-sortablejs instead